# How to change wxFont's font family on OSX?

Tags: macos, cocoa, fonts, wxwidgets

I have a paint function which look like this:

```
void doPaintBackground(wxDC &dc) {

    wxBrush  brush = wxBrush(*wBLACK_BRUSH) ;
    wxPen pen = wxPen(color_) ;
    dc.SetBrush(brush) ;
    dc.SetPen(pen) ;

    wxString Str = L"SOMETHING";
    wxFont font = dc.GetFont();
    font.SetFamily(wxFONTFAMILY_MODERN);
    dc.SetFont(font);   
    dc.DrawText(Str, 3, 0);
}
```

And this works on Windows and the family changes to `wxFONTFAMILY_MODERN`, but on OSX it always stays on `wxFONTFAMILY_DEFAULT`.
Can somebody tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in wxOSX, but you should be able to work around it by creating a new font with `wxFONTFAMILY_DEFAULT` and the same size etc as the current font. Be warned that under OS X "modern" family seems to just mean "fixed width", so I'm not sure how useful is it to set it.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to solve the problem with a new font